# Wubihua / Traditional Chinese / Open-source index

Tags: characters

I have been looking for an open-source index of Chinese characters (Traditional) indexed by the Wubihua (五筆劃). I have found only partial lists (up to four digits), and only for Simplified. I know there are lists out there, since all the phones in Hong Kong have Wubihua for Traditional installed... Any pointers?

Comment: Can you put the link to the Simplified partial lists?  It can serve as an example and might be helpful to others.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=wubihua 4th link is the more complete one, but only four digits, so pretty much useless...

Comment: For the record, the 4th link is http://developer.mimer.com/charts/chinese_wubihua.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you want to use it for? Mostly it is used as an input method, which is probably why only four digits are included. If you need the order of all strokes, changing your search phrase to something like "stroke order" might help. Here are some links I have found:

http://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/

http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-stroke-order.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E5%9C%8B

Edit: I've found this:

https://code.google.com/p/ibus-t9/issues/detail?id=3

Very inclusive! Download that attachment. I bet that is exactly what you are looking for. :)

Comment: +1 for the last link!

Comment: After review, this document is even a little too exhaustive, as it mixes Traditional and Simplified. Picky, I know... :) I wrote a script to weed out the chaff, and I think I have now a good list to start with. Thanks again!

Comment: @dda could you post that list please? Thanx