# Documentation of all hanzi and their stroke order

Tags: characters

Is there a document of all common hanzi (ideally both traditional and simplified) and their complete stroke orders? I have one for wubihua, but it fails to distinguish between, for example

> hs 丁 in reality h.sg
>
> hs 丅 in truth h.s

despite a flick at the bottom of 丁 but not 丅.

I've been looking for such a document so that I can analyse characters en masse, but haven't had any luck so far. [Wubihua / Traditional Chinese / Open-source index](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/wubihua-traditional-chinese-open-source-index) yieded good answers for wubihua, but taken more generally to all hanzi, does such a document exist with complete stroke order definition?

I'm looking for more of a plaintext document (or excel or similar) with a list. I know there are lots of images for stroke orders for learning characters, but I've been unable to find a file with a list of characters and their stroke "code", so to say

Comment: google：汉字笔顺 １st result：http://bishun.shufaji.com/

Comment: I was looking for more of a plaintext document (or excel or similar) with a big list. I know there are lots of images for stroke orders for learning characters, but I've been unable to find a big file with a list of all characters and their stroke "code", so to say

Answer (score 3):

I looked around, and it doesn't seem to be a complete, freely available resource for stroke orders. There is a [Wikimedia commons project](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Stroke_Order_Project) for creating stroke order for CJK characters, but it is far from finished (please contribute!).

I also found [this resource](http://dragon-char.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dragon-char/dragon-data/) from Dragon Character Training, an old PalmOS application, which seems to contain some character stroke order data, but I had some trouble figuring out how to extract stroke order from the character data. It should be possible, though, since an included script can animate character stroke orders.

I wish you best of luck!